# AWS security group between ALB and EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to configure an ALB on AWS with a target group consisting of EC2 instances. I try to create the following security groups using Terraform:

```
1) sg-alb (SG associated to the ALB):
   ----------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source 0.0.0.0/0
      HTTPS with source 0.0.0.0/0

   Outbound: 
      All traffic with destination 0.0.0.0/0 

  2) sg-http-alb (SG associated to the EC2 instances and should only receive traffic from the ALB):
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source sg-alb
      HTTPS with source sg-alb

   Outbound: 
      All traffic with destination 0.0.0.0/0
```

I read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html) that it's a best practice to limit the outbound traffic to the `instance security group` destination on the listener port.

So I changed the configuration as follows:

```
1) sg-alb (SG associated to the ALB):
   ----------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source 0.0.0.0/0
      HTTPS with source 0.0.0.0/0

   Outbound: 
      HTTP with destination sg-http-alb (<---- this line changed)

  2) sg-http-alb (SG associated to the EC2 instances and should only receive traffic from the ALB):
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source sg-alb
      HTTPS with source sg-alb

   Outbound: 
      All traffic with destination 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I configure this in Terraform I get `Error: Cycle:` which seem to indicates there is loop. Indeed I'm specifying from security group `sg-alb` to the instances `sg-http-alb` and from security group `sg-http-alb` I'm using security group `sg-alb` as a source. Both EC2 and ALB are in the same public subnet (there's reasons for that).

However using the console this is allowed. Also when I specify the internal IP address (using /32) of my EC2 instances as the outbound destination, it works but not sure if this is a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the circular reference you will need to split the security group rules out into [separate terraform resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) instead of defining them inline in the `security_group` resource.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, but that works indeed.